# android error Execution failed for task

Tags: android

hi all i'm facing a problem with this error in android how to solve this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zznf$zza.class

Comment: What did you do to get this error?

Comment: no changes in gradle file but it rises the error...

Comment: post your build.gradle file